# Сравнение группы надписей кнопок

Tags: angular2

Привет, в общем хочу сделать следующее, есть 2 группы баттонов(angular material "md-radio-button"), если какое-то из значений первой группы совпадает с любым из второй, сделать баттон неактивным и добавить какой-то текст.
К примеру в 1 группе есть :

> -Москва
>   -СПБ
>   -Воронеж

Во второй есть:

> -Краснодар
>   -Чебаркуль
>   -Воронеж

Тогда в 1 группе сделать баттон Воронеж неактивным и добавить текст.
Здесь код:
https://plnkr.co/edit/3QdQtu4kWCQjL5uO2kJt?p=preview

Мои мысли ведут меня в сторону - `[disabled] = "selectedcountry === selectedcopycountry"`, такой же *ngIf c текстом к баттону, но ведь тогда считаются значения только с выбранного ... В общем прошу помощи

Comment: Планкер дохлый. Возможно, ты забыл forms module.

Comment: Спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно было быть что-то такое

```
[disabled]="countries.includes(country)"
```

но т. к. там лежат объекты, то функцию для поиска надо вынести в компонент

```
hasCountry(country) {
  return this.countries && this.countries.some(c => c.name === country.name);
}
```

и вызывать её

```
[disabled]="hasCountry(country)"
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ufz70Kx89YtWLglFPfck?p=preview

Comment: Спасибо большое, а можете объяснить как именно работает функция this.countries.some(c => c.name === country.name); и как добавить текст 
 рядом к disabled button?

Comment: Проходит в цикле по массиву и на первом совпадении делает return true.